# Spring Cloud dataflow Yarn integration with Spark

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to integrate Spring Cloud dataflow Yarn SPI with Spark running on Hortonworks sandbox 2.4. Does anyone have any samples on the configuration that we need to do? My Spark program is executing properly when I run it using spark-submit, but giving problems when I ran through Spring Cloud dataflow after registering the Spark app. There may be some prerequisites that I need to set and not sure of what all they are.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by taking a look at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task-app-starters.

Hope this helps,
Marius